# Trying to JOIN table of transactional data (and aggregate on the fly) using between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query to check an import table of aggregated data against the source system (transactional data). I feel like it should be simple, but I can't seem to get it figured.

The aggregate table (let's call it DW) looks like this:

| NameID | StartTime | EndTime | Material | Total | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:15:00.000 | 2022-12-05 01:57:00.000 | TAM | 26 | 4 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:15:00.000 | 2022-12-05 01:57:00.000 | BVO | 32 | 5 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:15:00.000 | 2022-12-04 23:11:00.000 | TAM | 54 | 3 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:15:00.000 | 2022-12-04 23:11:00.000 | BVO | 106 | 6 |

Total is the sum of Amount from the SRC table (below) and Count is the count of records that match the NameID and Material and occur between StartTime and EndTime.

I want to check against the source table to make sure the pipeline that picks up the information aggregated everything correctly.

Source Table (let's call it SRC) looks like this:

| NameID | TimeStamp | Material | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 22:15:56.000 | TAM | 3 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:17:02.000 | TAM | 5 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:18:06.000 | TAM | 7 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:19:14.000 | TAM | 11 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:20:19.000 | BVO | 1 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:21:19.000 | BVO | 6 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:22:33.000 | BVO | 9 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:23:36.000 | CAD | 2 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:24:53.000 | BVO | 6 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:25:56.000 | TAM | 3 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:27:23.000 | CAD | 8 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:28:25.000 | BVO | 10 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 18:15:56.000 | TAM | 11 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:17:02.000 | TAM | 20 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:18:06.000 | TAM | 33 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:19:14.000 | TAM | 1 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:20:19.000 | BVO | 7 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:21:19.000 | BVO | 22 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:22:33.000 | BVO | 31 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:23:36.000 | CAD | 7 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:24:53.000 | BVO | 11 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:25:56.000 | BVO | 21 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:27:23.000 | CAD | 29 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:28:25.000 | BVO | 14 |

*I included 2 timestamped records that shouldn't match and also 4 material records that don't match

Ideally, I'm looking for a result set that would be an extension of the DW table by having columns represent the totals from the SRC table:

| NameID | StartTime | EndTime | Material | Total | Count | Total - SRC | Count - SRC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:15:00.000 | 2022-12-05 01:57:00.000 | TAM | 26 | 4 | 26 | 4 |
| 19Test | 2022-12-04 23:15:00.000 | 2022-12-05 01:57:00.000 | BVO | 32 | 5 | 32 | 5 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:15:00.000 | 2022-12-04 23:11:00.000 | TAM | 54 | 3 | 54 | 3 |
| 20Test | 2022-12-04 20:15:00.000 | 2022-12-04 23:11:00.000 | BVO | 106 | 6 | 106 | 6 |

I've tried something like below:

```
SELECT dw.NameID, dw.StartTime, dw.EndTime, dw.Material, dw.Total, dw.Count, src.Total, src.Count
FROM dw
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(src.Amount) Total, count(*) count, src.NameID, src.Material
    FROM src
    WHERE src.NameID = dw.NameID
    AND src.SampleDateTime BETWEEN dw.StartTime AND dw.EndTime
    GROUP BY src.NameID, d.Material
) as d on dw.NameID = d.NameID
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 80
> The multi-part identifier "dw.Machine" could not be bound.

I've thought about using a cursor and temp tables to loop through and aggregate the data from the SRC table based on records from the DW table, but I think there's a more efficient (and easier) way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're definitely on the right path, you've just overcomplicated it imo.

Instead of the subquery, just leave it as a normal JOIN. Then with a few minor updates to grouping and some column name & join fixes:

```
SELECT dw.NameID, dw.StartTime, dw.EndTime, dw.Material, dw.Total, dw.Count, 
       SUM(src.Amount) AS Total_SRC, count(*) AS Count_SRC
FROM   dw
       INNER JOIN src ON dw.NameID = src.NameID
                   AND dw.Material = src.Material 
                   AND src.SampleDateTime BETWEEN dw.StartTime AND dw.EndTime
GROUP BY dw.NameID, dw.StartTime, dw.EndTime, dw.Material, dw.Total, dw.Count
```

Result are as below, and can be seen in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/boz8NsVl)

```
NameID  StartTime                EndTime                  Material  Total  Count  Total_SRC  Count_SRC
19Test  2022-12-04 23:15:00.000  2022-12-05 01:57:00.000  BVO       32     5      32         5
19Test  2022-12-04 23:15:00.000  2022-12-05 01:57:00.000  TAM       26     4      26         4
20Test  2022-12-04 20:15:00.000  2022-12-04 23:11:00.000  BVO       106    6      106        6
20Test  2022-12-04 20:15:00.000  2022-12-04 23:11:00.000  TAM       54     3      54         3
```

Note - if you need to run this frequently and/or want quick results, I'd look at the indexing on the src table. Indeed, I would probably either

- Put the clustered index on Name_Id, Material, SampleDateTime (in order)
- Put a non-clustered index on those fields, and INCLUDE Amount (though this basically creates a copy of the whole table)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I think I even tried this query previously but didn't work at the time, so I thought it was me. I've come to realize it was because I was coding the material incorrectly in the aggregate table, so it wasn't matching. Regardless, I'm super glad this got me going again. Thank you!

Comment: Using the below suggestion, I improved on this by adding 

HAVING SUM(src.Amount)<> dw.Total OR COUNT(*) <> dw.Count 

This gave me only the differences which is great for a larger data set. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of thinking, since you want to *check the imported table of aggregated data against the source system table*, you could use the `EXCEPT` operator as the following:

> The SQL EXCEPT clause/operator is used to combine two SELECT statements and returns rows from the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement. This means EXCEPT returns only rows, which are not available in the second SELECT statement.

```
Select NameID,
       StartTime,
       EndTime,
       Material,
       Total,
       [Count]
From DW
Except
Select S.NameID, 
       D.StartTime,
       D.EndTime,
       S.Material,
       Sum(S.Amount) As Total,
       Count(*) As [Count]
From SRC S Join DW D
On S.NameID = D.NameID And S.Material  = D.Material
   And S.TimeStamp Between D.StartTime And D.EndTime
Group By S.NameID, S.Material, D.StartTime, D.EndTime
```

So *no rows will be returned by this query* when all of imported table rows are found in the aggregated data from the source table, which means that the imported table is aggregated correctly.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9tRK1MLH).

Comment: A query to show the exceptions vs showing all results. I really like this as well. The first comment was the query I was thinking of. However, I really like this take on the problem.

Comment: I trialed this and the one problem is that it doesn't show me what the SRC values are so that I know what the difference is.

However! I was able to use this take on things and edit the above query to show me only the exceptions (which is optimal format for me in this case). Thanks!